# From where energy comes for the heat released when direction of electric field is changed with a dipole placed in the field

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, dipole

[image]
This is an example problem in my book. Forget about the values.

Initial anf final(after heat is released) conditions in this problem are same, ie, dipole moment and electric field are in same direction. We know that energy of a configuration is same irrespective of how it is created. Then how there is release of heat, from where energy is coming in to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the direction of the field changes suddenly, the dipoles rotate quickly and, as a result, when they reach the new orientation, they have some kinetic energy, which will turn into heat, i.e., some energy will be released.

This kinetic energy is equal the difference of potential energies corresponding to the initial orientation of the dipoles and two directions of the electric field.

The energy, naturally, comes from the electric field, which cause the change in polarization.

Comment: How can polarity change when there is a permanent dipole? Are these two things different?

Comment: @TontyTon By change in polarization, I mean change in orientation. The dipole is permanent in a sense that the distance between pos. and neg. charges of a dipole molecule (or the dipole moment) does not change: it does not depend on the presence, strength or dir. of electric field. In reality, molecules may stretch under influence of electric field, which increases their  dipole moment. So, you can think of perm. dipoles just changing their orientation as the orient. of electric field changes and if it is sudden, they gain some angular velocity, hence kinetic energy, which turns into heat.

Comment: @TontyTon Happy to help.